# Doing an AJAX request to a website that might be up, or might be down

Tags: ajax

I'm writing a small app that will be used to monitor the status of a few websites, mainly just to report which websites are online and which websites are offline.

I currently have this code as the *onreadystatechange* function:

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        element(id).innerHTML = "Online";
    }
    else {
        element(id).innerHTML = "Offline";
    }
}
```

It runs properly when the website is online, but it never reaches the 'else' block if I do an AJAX request on a website that is offline.. I'm thinking the request never reaches readyState 4 if the website is down?

Any suggestions for how to capture an AJAX request to an offline website?

Comment: An alternative approach is to have a hidden IFRAME pointed at each page, and put onload and onerror event handlers on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is abort the request after a specific amount of time, i.e. a *timeout*. Here's an article that should help:

[Async Requests over an Unreliable Network](http://ajaxblog.com/archives/2005/06/01/async-requests-over-an-unreliable-network)

Comment: Yeah, I did some investigating, and when you do an AJAX request to a resource that is offline, the readyState never reaches 4, it stays at 1 until you abort the request.

Answer (score 1):

IE8's XHR object supports an ontimeout event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197061(VS.85).aspx)

ReadyState=4 means "loaded", which won't happen if the content doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested now using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and it returned Status 502, Body 512

Comment: Yeah, but my else block should be catching anything that isn't a 200. For some reason it doesn't

Comment: A 502 is generated by a proxy if the server is not reachable. If there's no proxy, there will be no 502.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the header for a 404 error.

Comment: You won't get a 404 from a downed server, since the server isn't up to return the 404.